# I want a command to apt-get Tensorflow on robot Nao

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nao-robot

I want to install TensorFlow framework in robot NAO , if i do :

```
ssh nao@192.168.1.3
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
```

he print an error :

```
-bash: apt-get: command not found
```

so How can i install tensorflow framework on robot NAO?

Comment: But do you know that NAO has a very very poor gpu ?

Comment: Yup i want to work with CPU !

Comment: The cpu is a bit limitated also...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no apt-get tool on your NAO, because NAO has different portage method, although its os is Linux. Generally two approaches you can go with:

1. if you have NAO simulator, first install the Tensorflow on it, and then copy all files to you NAO robot, so you have apt-get tool on your simulator and no mess on robot.
2. or you can install packages per pip tool, but NAO's os is [Gentoo](https://gentoo.org/), so it could be a little twisted.

First search pip

```
emerge -s pip
```

Find the name of tools you need, such as dev-python/pip and others python packages, to install it superuser is required.

```
emerge dev-python/pip
```

Then you can begin other tasks.

I am not familiar with Tensorflow, however if you can not install it, you can built it from source code.
BTY, you might wanna check [emerge command](https://dev.gentoo.org/~zmedico/portage/doc/man/emerge.1.html).